# Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc2 Install Build Tools 24.0.0 rc2 and sync project

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

It is my developed project with target API 23. Now I'm using Studio 2.1.3

When I am trying to open this project the error show me like `Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc2 Install Build Tools 24.0.0 rc2 and sync project`

But when I try to install, then a error message shown.

It was a big project, I have to run it. How can I sync it and run it properly? Please help me, Thanks in advance..

Screenshot 1: this is the error message

[image]

Screenshot 2: when i click to install and sync then this error message has appeared
[image]

Comment: Open the SDK manager, check which build tools you have, install the latest and update the version in your module build.gradle file. (Latest version is 24.0.2, no release candidate.)

Comment: I have already updated but there is same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Update the `android-sdk` tools to the newest version: `24.0.2`
Change your Android Support libraries version like `appcompat` from `23.x.x` version to `24.2.0`

If you would any problem with updating dependencies, check: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager

**Tip:** Try to avoid use in your project `alpha`,`preview` or `beta` versions of project dependencies.

Hope it will help

Comment: all android-sdk tools has been updated, but there is same problem.... :(

how can I change Android Support libraries version like appcompat from 23.x.x version to 24.2.0 ??

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your *module's* `build.gradle` file there's a specification which build tools the module uses. Fix it to latest.

```
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection to google servers.Some countries like Iran should use VPN to connect.

Hop it work

Answer (score 0):

Go to build.gradle(Module:app) and update the `buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc2'` to `buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'` or to the latest version